# [ActionSheetPicker respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, actionsheetpicker

I have a problem with "ActionSheetPicker" in iOS 7.0 works fine but 7.1 is broken:

```
[ActionSheetPicker showPickerWithTitle: [Language get: @ "ChooseLocation" alter: @ ""]
                                               rows: actionSheetPickerCityList
                                   initialSelection: 0
                                             target: self
                                             action: @ selector (cityWasSelected: element :)
                                             origin: self.view];
```

I get this error:

```
*** - [ActionSheetPicker respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd4e42c0
```

And do not understand why, driving me crazy because in ios 6 and 7.0 works correctly. The action I do is saved in an array (`actionSheetPickerCityList`) a list of cities and when I select one of these breaks.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have an issue about this on GitHub : https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker/issues/100

Since **ActionSheetPicker** is a GitHub component you should check issues first :-)

Hop this helps

Comment: Thanks, you can accept my answer by checking the green tick at left.